# send axios post request in vuejs

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

i want to send axios post request from my template in vuejs looks like the following code :

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      body:{
       name:'ssdsdsd',
       time:'232342',
      },
    header:{headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }},
      name:null,
      r:null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    post:function(){
      this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1/saver.php',this.body,this.header).then(r => {
       this.r=r;
       // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
       console.log(typeof this.body)
      }).catch(err => {
   // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
   console.log(err.response.data)
});
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

and i get this.name (name) in php code with Requst method

this is my php code :

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo($_REQUEST['name']);

?>
```

but php returned this response :

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp64\www\saver.php on line <i>4</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0003</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>401952</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\saver.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\saver.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

Comment: is there error when you do catch()?

Comment: @Evan no error :/ ?

Comment: when you  post a request does the page refresh? if so can you show us the template code

Comment: @Evan i think , problem be from the header ? isn't it ?

Comment: @Evan No dosn't refresh .

Comment: Can you show what params are sent to server? From browser's console. In farefox it's tab "Network" -> "Params". Are you sure you have assigned `axios` to `this.$http`?

Comment: Also, can you show `print_r($_REQUEST)`?

Comment: @webprogrammer yes axios correctly work because i tested  it for get json data from  an api , but in post method, i have problem with axios this is request payload : {"name":"asd"}

Comment: @webprogrammer : 
I used print_r  and got this response :  Array
(
    [{"name":"asd"}] => 
)

Answer (score 0):

**Upd.**

You get `Array ( [{"name":"asd"}] => )` but you should get this:

```
Array ( ["name" => "asd"])
```

**Upd. 2**

Can you try to remove `'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',` from your headers in axios?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206666/discussion-on-answer-by-webprogrammer-send-axios-post-request-in-vuejs).